# Group by with where condition in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, group-by

How can I write the following query in Mongo

```
select * from (
     select Domain, count(*) domainCount from MappedSites group by Domain
)
where domainCount > 1
```

I did the inner query:

```
db.MappedSites.group({
   key:{'Domain':true}, 
   cond: { 'State':0 },   
   reduce: function(doc, prev){prev.csum++;} ,   
   initial: {csum: 0} 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry by I'm having trouble following what you are trying to do differently from what you have already done. Could you explain it further? Perhaps provide some schema or explain in English (vs SQL) what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to get all the domains that appears more then once and for those domains the appearance count